# Information of authenticated user using firebase didn't appear in React Native

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, npm, expo

I used firebase to login into my app then I tried to display the user information using the following code in the figure below, but the output just display the email of the user. Does anyone know how I can display all the information?

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image, View } from 'react-native';

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"



export default class Profile extends Component {



  state = { user: {} };
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user != null) {
        this.setState({ user: user });
      }
    })

  }
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
        <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50 }} source={{ uri: this.state.user.photoUrl }} />
        <Text>{this.state.user.givenName}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.user.familyName}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.user.photoUrl}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.user.email}</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should updateProfile when login and add all data there. like this

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: "Jane Q. User", photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q- 
user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Profile updated!
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```